# How do i create my own right click menu on the desktop?

Tags: vb.net

i have searched up and down the internet but cannot figure this out. So ive finally come here for the aid of some utter genius people.

I dont like the windows right click function as it has too many options. Some of the options like properties cannot be removed. So, i thought i could disable right click to remove the menu and create my own.

The problem i have is i cannot figure out for VS2010 how to right click on the desktop outside of the form/project and make a box pop up like the same behaviour as the built in one. I am ultimately wanting to be able to expand and add things but im falling at the first hurdle.

Can someone please tell me how to right click on the desktop and create a context menu popup where i can add my own items. i want it to behave the same as windows but i want it my own essentially. This way in the future i will be able to enable or disable my own functions i.e open/winrar/7zip / remove edit on the fly.

thanks

Ka0s

Answer (score 0):

Remove/Disable the default menu of desktop is not a good idea at all

But you can add your own items as well using 3rd party apps
I made an app modifies the default menu ,it can append more items an sub items
I wrote it long time ago  I do not remember if i still have the source code or not

[App link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LKNyq1NU6QPKf29h1Tf4-ul2NKEjFUb9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I dont want to remove it just make my own. This was done by disabling right click ill check out ur link later. Thank you!.would still like to know how to right click off a form. I read about hooks but im nt that good as im new to this and then have a form pop up at the right click location